# Enforcing data integrity only after transaction completes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unique-constraint

I have a schema as follows:

```
CounterParty  PersonalInfo  TwoRows
============  ============  =======
Id            Id            Id
Type          Name          
              Surname
```

Tables CounterParty and PersonalInfo are in one to one relationship.

Then I got a view that contains CounterParty

```
create view V_CHK_CounterParty_Name
with schemabinding
as
select c.Id from CounterParty c
join PersonalInfo p on p.Id = c.Id and p.Name is null and
c.Type = 2
cross join TwoRows
```

and a unique key upon its Id column, where if a row gets selected, it will be duplicated due to the cross join and cause unique key violation.

I also got another view, very similar, but this one checks for if Surname is null and Type = 1. It is named **V_CHK_CounterParty_Surname**

**The problem**

When I try to change a record from Type=1 to 2 and erase Surname and fill out the Name I violate the UK constraint. This happens because I need to update first one tables data and then other ones, causing an error. Can I treat this two-table update as a single query? There are some cases when Surname and Name are both filled out, then there is no problem.

Is there a way to ensure data integrity on database level even when shared across tables like this?

***EDIT:***
I will provide some data to better illustrate the error.

Data before the transaction:

```
CounterParty          PersonalInfo       TwoRows
============          ============       =======
Id: 4444              Id: 5879           Id: 1
Type: 1               Name: NULL         =======
IdPersonalInfo: 5879  Surname: "Cane"    Id: 2
```

Data I would like to be there after transaction:

```
CounterParty          PersonalInfo       TwoRows
============          ============       =======
Id: 4444              Id: 5879           Id: 1
Type: 2               Name: "John"       =======
IdPersonalInfo: 5879  Surname: NULL      Id: 2
```

How I try to do it: I actually use entity framework, but the SQL that is being run is:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE CounterParty
SET Type = 2
WHERE Id = 4444;

/*UK gets violated, because we are now in state where data projects into the view, gets cross-joined with TwoRows and immediately violate UK constraint.*/

UPDATE PersonalInfo
SET Surname = NULL, Name = 'John'
WHERE Id = 5879;

COMMIT;
```

Note it does not matter in which order I choose to update the tables. Also I cannot merge the two as multiple other tables are in one to one relationship with PersonalInfo.

Unique key definition:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UK_V_CHK_CounterParty_Name ON
V_CHK_CounterParty_Name
( Id ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And another one Called **UK_V_CHK_CounterParty_Surname** which is exactly the same but works upon V_CHK_CounterParty_Surname.

Comment: Can you add some sample data (as formatted text), before and after, that illustrates this issue. And also provide the definition of your unique constraint.

Comment: As these have a one to one relationship you would be better off moving the Counterparty type column into PersonalInfo  - then you could just add simple check constraints to enforce there are no rows where Name is null and CounterParty type is 2 and that there are no rows where Surname is null and CounterParty type is 1

Comment: @MartinSmith The PersonalInfo table is being used by many more tables that share the fields Name, Surname and many more. All are in one to one relationship. Edited post and made it more clear I hope.

Comment: Some database systems support deferred checking of constraints, which allows temporary violations provided that they're remedied before the transaction commits. SQL Server isn't one of them.

Comment: Does this mean I should turn to e.g. add extra value that indicates the values are being edited and the views should Ignore such data?